# Plotting multiple grouped variable datasets in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot multiple datasets that have grouped variables in ggplot and I am running into a few problems.  OK, so I have two datasets:

```
df.1 <- data.frame(
name = c( "a", "b", "c", "d" ),
x = c( 3, 2, 1, 2 ),
y = c( 4, 3, 4, 3 ),
z = c( 8, 9, 6, 7 ) )

df.2 <- data.frame(
name = c( "o", "p", "q", "r" ),
x = c( 8, 7, 6, 9 ),
y = c( 4, 1, 4, 3 ),
z = c( 1, 2, 2, 2 ) )
```

And then I melt each of them to group by name

```
df.1.melted  <- melt( df.1, id.vars = "name" )
df.2.melted  <- melt( df.2, id.vars = "name" )
```

Now, I want a plot where the x-axis has `x`, `y`, and `z` grouped and the y-axis is the value, with each sample linked by the `name` already given to it.  I can do this for one of the datasets (I want a log scale eventually so it's included):

```
ggplot( df.1.melted, aes( x = variable, 
                          y = value, 
                          group = df.1.melted$name, 
                          col = df.1.melted$name ) ) +
scale_y_continuous( trans = log_trans(), limits = c( 1, 10 ), 
                    breaks = c( 1, 10 ) ) +
labs( x = "", y = "value" ) +
geom_point( size = 4 ) +
geom_line( size = 1 )
```

Which gives me something reasonable:
[image]

Then I can add the second data set by:

```
ggplot( df.1.melted, aes( x = variable, 
                          y = value, 
                          group = df.1.melted$name, 
                          col = df.1.melted$name ) ) +
scale_y_continuous( trans = log_trans(), limits = c( 1, 10 ), 
                    breaks = c( 1, 10 ) ) +
labs( x = "", y = "value" ) +
geom_point( size = 4 ) +
geom_line( size = 1 ) +

geom_point( data = df.2.melted, aes( x = df.2.melted$variable,
                                     y = df.2.melted$value, 
                                     group = df.2.melted$name, 
                                     col = df.2.melted$name ), 
            size = 4 ) +
geom_line( data = df.2.melted, aes( x = df.2.melted$variable,
                                    y = df.2.melted$value, 
                                    group = df.2.melted$name, 
                                    col = df.2.melted$name ), 
           size = 1 )
```

which yields:
[image]

This is the main theme of what I am after, but I'm running into a few problems:
1) How can I overwrite the default color schemes when using the `aes( group = ...)` portion?  I want to either have predefined colors in the data frame or be able to define them in `geom_point()`.  The colors should be particular to the dataframe that I'm using, so `df.1.melted` is `darkgreen` and `df.2.melted` is `orange` or something like that.  I haven't found how to plot these without using the `group =` in the `aes()` call, so I can't find a workaround at the moment.

The solution looks possible, as in the `ggplot` example in the answer here:
[R plotly - Plotting grouped lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43648750/r-plotly-plotting-grouped-lines)

But, I am not familiar enough with `dplyr` to figure out what is going on to create this plot.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: scale_colour_manual lets you manually assign colours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df_melted <- bind_rows(df.1.melted, df.2.melted)
df_melted %>% 
 mutate(df = rep(c('df.1', 'df.2'), each = nrow(df_melted) / 2)) %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x = variable,
            y = value,
            col = df)) +
 geom_line(aes(group = name)) +
 geom_point() +
 scale_y_log10(limits = c( 1, 10), 
               breaks = c(1, 10)) +
 scale_color_manual(values = c('df.1' = "forestgreen",
                               'df.2' = "orange"))
```

[image]

The idea is to create one data frame, `df_melted`, and add the column `df` that indicates from which data frame the observations came from. Then you can map variable `df` to the colour aesthetic. As suggested in the comment you can change the default colours using `scale_colour_manual`.

Comment: Ahh ok.  So this is exactly what I'm looking for.  Could you walk me through what the `mutate()` function is doing?  Sorry, I'm still a bit new at this and I don't follow what happens after the first pipethrough.

Comment: `mutate` adds new variables. You could also do this `df$new_variable <- "a string"`. see `?mutate` for details or read about this function in [R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#add-new-variables-with-mutate)

Comment: @Jesse, just one more comment on your plot. It is recommended *not* to refer to variables with `$` in `aes()`. This might cause problems. Use variable names only, i.e. use `var` instead of `df$var`.

Comment: Hi @markus, thanks for the plotting tip, that makes complete sense.   I'm still getting confused with the pipethrough use and can't figure out what the final dataframe looks like.  What is in it that is being plotted?  Sorry for my ignorance here..

Comment: There is not happening much. Take a look at `df_melted` before you call `mutate` etc. The next step simply adds the following vector to it `rep(c('df.1', 'df.2'), each = nrow(df_melted) / 2)` and calls it `df`.